# A question about spot rate forward rate and swap rate

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics

[image: Please see the questions below]

A term structure is given as follows. The market convention is compound interest, that is, the present value of one unit at time T is...

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and what is your difficulty.

Comment: Agreed with @Gordon, this looks like your homework which we are not going to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework and no attempt has been shown to it.

Comment: http://se.u.94y.info for a list of potential resources